# OpenCV: Image segmentation of greyscale image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, watershed

I have the following EM image of brain tissue and I am trying to segment the neurons.

[image]

The following is what the segmented result should look like:

[image]

I am trying to do Watershed segmentation to segment the image. However, when trying to create a binary mask (using simple thresholding in OpenCV), I do not get a very good mask at all because of the dark round features in the image (circled in red).

[image]

Here is the mask I got below:

[image]

```
# code used to get the mask
img_smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_grey, (21,21), 0)
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(img_smooth, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Is there any way that one can replace these dark round features with grey using simple techniques like filtering/thresholding? Or is there no way to remove these round dark features through simple techniques and machine learning methods are necessary to accomplish this task? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: If i visually observe the images, it's hard to tell the pixel difference (or mathematically express the pixel difference) for the pixels need to be segmented from other pixels. If you already have some manual masks in hand, then you can try deep learning models like UNET, which i have already worked with, and provides good results for such cases.

Comment: Please add your original input image. A potential approach is to adaptive threshold, perform morphological transformations, then do contour area filtering. Other methods would be to use Canny edge detection to isolate the neurons but it's kinda hard to tell without your original image :)

Comment: I have added the original image. Would morphological transformations be recommended in order to remove noise/close holes in the binary image?

Comment: To clarify, the 2nd image is the expected result (mask) or do you want the result after applying the mask? Yes morphological operations can help to close holes or erode small noise away

Comment: Yes, the 2nd image is the expected result.